# LSTM Model not improve on sentiment analysis, what im doing wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, data-mining

I have sentiment data that contains 3 labels (positive, negative, neutral)
and i have 3233 row data, already tested on naive bayes and svm model, my data got 90 % accuracy on naive bayes, and 92 % accuracy on SVM

this is my model

```
EMBED_DIM = 16
LSTM_OUT = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(total_words, EMBED_DIM, input_length = x.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_OUT, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer =optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint   # save model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    'models/LSTM.h5',
    monitor='accuracy',
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 5, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

the result is stuck at around 30% and not improving
Thank you!

i already tried to change the model removing spatialDropout1D
using 1 layer lstm
changing the lstm unit and embed dimension
also changning the dropout value

already tried using sigmoid for the activation and binary crossentropy

Comment: How long are your x.shape[1]? LSTM doesn't work well if your seq_len is too large (>50).

Comment: its 3233 word have a lot of zeros, because i use tf idf for weighting my word, if i added maxlen on my pad_sequences, its all replaces by zeros for value below 1, do you have any suggestion to improve my work ?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used tf_idf. But I know lstm can't process too long secuences. So you have to ensure that your seq_len is less than 50 (from my experience) in order to make it work.

Comment: ill try your suggestion @TheEngineerProgrammer thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I used Flatten in my layer and my target was a binary result.  I was able to achieve about 80% accuracy using the model

```
word_count=[]
word_count = [len(x.split()) for x in df['Text'].tolist()]
#print(words)
max_length = np.max(word_count)
vocab_size=70

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 1, input_length=max_length))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer =optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(padded_docs, target, epochs=3, verbose=1)

model.summary()

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs, target, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))
```